# .gitignore node_modules/ not working for fd and ripgrep

Tags: fzf, ripgrep, vim-fzf

I'm trying to setup [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) for vim on windows 10.

You can use an alternative find command like [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) or [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) which is supposed to [respect .gitignore](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#respecting-gitignore).

My .gitignore file has this line, which is working fine for git commits, etc.:

```
node_modules/
```

My dir structure is

```
/working directory
.gitignore file
.git  dir
/node_modules dir
```

When I run

```
fd --type f
```

or

```
rg --files
```

It lists all files in node_modules.

I feel like this may be a windows problem.

How can I get these programs to use .gitignore to ignore node_modules?

Comment: Use ripgrep's --debug flag to scrutinize how gitignore rules are being applied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out, I was using a project where the git repo had not yet been initialized. So I had a .gitignore, but did not have a .git folder. And by default ripgrep needs it to be an actual git repository to utilize the .gitiginore folder.  My solution was to use the following flag -

> --no-require-git

[More info here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/commit/d0659282e65dde46e0b5f373d89042b2fe1d4884)

Comment: I would not have guessed it the init repo issue. Save me a lot of time! Thank you!